# Corrupted PDF When Saving to Database over 50kB

Tags: ajax, pdf, flask, blob, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a webpage where the user can upload a PDF file and send it using AJAX to my Flask application. Here is the ajax code:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('attachment', document.getElementById("attachment").files[0]);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'process_award_storage',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: formData
})
```

I do not think that this has any problems because I can print out the content and title of file in the python code. Then my flask model is defined as such, using LargeBinary for the PDF attachment:

```
class AwardStore(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'awards_store'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
    file = db.Column(db.LargeBinary, nullable=True) #I am sure this is the right file type for PDF saving
```

Lastly, here is how the AJAX file is saved to the database:

```
     award = AwardStore(name=name, file=request.files['attachment'].read())
     db.session.add(award)
     db.session.commit()
```

I can see using my MySQL Workbench that it is saved. However, when I try to download the BLOB from there to the Desktop and open it, it says "Failed to load PDF document". The same happens when I use flask's `send_file`. It seems like I did everything as I saw online, but something is wrong.

Maybe these warnings are related?:

```
C:\Users\msolonko\Desktop\NICKFI~1\CACHTM~1\APP_DE~1\virt\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:170: Warning: (1300, "Invalid utf8 character string: 'C4E5F2'")
  result = self._query(query)
C:\Users\msolonko\Desktop\NICKFI~1\CACHTM~1\APP_DE~1\virt\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:170: Warning: (1265, "Data truncated for column 'file' at row 1")
  result = self._query(query)
```

I tried googling them and did not find anything. I appreciate any assistance.

EDIT:

I noticed that small files are typically uploaded and displayed properly. The issue is with files with sizes > ~50kB. The database I am using the AWS RDS, Is there a setting I can change somewhere to enable greater sizes?

Comment: See if this helps ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31849494/serve-image-stored-in-sqlalchemy-largebinary-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LargeBinary accepts a length field also.
which converts to mysql's BLOB whose default length is 65535 bytes (64kb).
Try increasing the length and set it to

a MEDIUMBLOB for 16777215 bytes (16 MB)

a LONGBLOB for 4294967295 bytes (4 GB).

Hope this will help