# Python - save BytesIO in database

Tags: python, database, flask, redis, sendfile

So I am trying to create a binary file and save it into my database. I am using REDIS and SQLALCHEMY as a framework for my database. I can use `send_file` to send the actual file whenever the user accesses a URL but how do I make sure that the file is saved in the route and it could stay there every time a user accesses the URL.

> I am sending the file from a client-python it's not in my
>   directory

what I need in a nutshell is to save the file from the client-python to a database to "downloadable" it to the browser-client so it would actually be available for the browser-client is there any way of doing this? Maybe a different way that I didn't think about

Comment: This depends on the database you're using. If it supports a blob (binary large object) type, you can do it directly, otherwise you may need to encode the data using something like base64 to make sure it survives the trip through the database. It can definitely be done, but please share what you tried and ask questions about it if you cannot get it to work. By the way: not exactly your question, but relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31849494/serve-image-stored-in-sqlalchemy-largebinary-column

Comment: @Grismar I told you, I prefer to use redis  but sqlalchemy could do if there is really no way to do it in redis. I didn't try anything yet because I didn't know how to do it but the option of turning it to base64 could work I guess

Comment: @Grismar I wanted also to know if somehow there is a easier way of doing this

Comment: Redis is an in-memory data store. There seems to be little point to use something so specialised to do something as simple as keeping files in memory. Why not just stick the bytes in a dict and serve them back from there? If your aim is not to keep them in memory, then why are you asking to use Redis? And in that case, why not just save the files to disk, what are you hoping to gain from using a database at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to encode the data with base64, send it to the database and then decode it and send the file as binary data.