# How to display image on html from SQLAlchemy LargBinary column

Tags: python, html, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm writing a gallery web app that saves photos and display them.
I'm using SQLAlchemy for the database and store the image in a LargeBinary column.
When I try to display every image I run into the problme that for displaying html image you need the url for the `<img src=` and I dont know how to reach the url of the BinaryData column in the
database, is there a different way? (I dont want to save all images in a folder because i already have then stored in the database)

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect, send_file
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime
from io import BytesIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class GalleryImage(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    pic = db.Column(db.LargeBinary, nullable=False)
    content = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    date_time = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Gl %r>' % self.id
```

**I transfred the elements to html script, I did not save the images in a folder because they are saved in the database**

```
{% for pic in gallery %}
<div class="gallery">
    <img src=WHAT TO WRITE HERE!? alt="Img" width="100" height="100">
    <div class="desc">{{pic.name}}, <br> {{pic.content}}</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31849494/serve-image-stored-in-sqlalchemy-largebinary-column

Answer (score 0):

**In .py**

```
def get_images():
images = db.session.query(GalleryImage).all()
image_list = []
# read image data from db back to form a rendable in html
for img in images:
    image = base64.b64encode(img.pic).decode('ascii')
    image_list.append(image)
return render_template('gallery.html', image_list=image_list)
```

**In .html**

```
<ul>
{% if image_list|length == 0 %}
<p>Add some Images to the Gallery</p>
{% else %}
{% for image in image_list %}
<li>
<img src="data:;base64,{{image}}"/>
</li>
</ul>
```

Worked for me